# Elasticsearch speed vs. Cloud (localhost to production)

Tags: elasticsearch, vue.js, kibana, elastic-stack

I have got a single ELK stack with a single node running in a vagrant virtual box on my machine. It has 3 indexes which are 90mb, 3.6gb, and 38gb.

At the same time, I have also got a Javascript application running on the host machine, consuming data from Elasticsearch which runs no problem, speed and everything's perfect. (Locally)

The issue comes when I put my Javascript application in production, as the Elasticsearch endpoint in the application has to go from `localhost:9200` to `MyDomainName.com:9200`. The speed of the application runs fine within the company, but when I access it from home, the speed drastically decreases and often crashes. However, when I go to Kibana from home, running query there is fine.

The company is using BT broadband and has a download speed of 60mb, and 20mb upload. Doesn't use fixed IP so have to update A record whenever IP changes manually, but I don't think is relevant to the problem.

Is the internet speed the main issue that affected the loading speed outside of the company? How do I improve this? Is cloud (CDN?) the only option that would make things run faster? If so how much would it cost to host it in the cloud assuming I would index a lot of documents in the first time, but do a daily max. 10mb indexing after?

**UPDATE1: Metrics from sending a request from Home using Chrome > Network**

```
Queued at 32.77s
Started at 32.77s

Resource Scheduling
- Queueing 0.37 ms

Connection Start
- Stalled 38.32s
- DNS Lookup 0.22ms
- Initial Connection 

Request/Response
- Request sent 48 μs
- Waiting (TTFB) 436.61.ms
- Content Download 0.58 ms
```

**UPDATE2:**
The stalling period seems to been much lesser when I use a VPN?

Comment: We have absolutely no idea without real world metrics being shown.

Comment: Being a javascript application, did you monitor network traffic to see what requests are crashing, you can leverage developer tools in chrome or similar in other web browsers.

Comment: I have updated the post with metrics of a stalled request sent from home